# cpp ImGui::CheckBox registers clicks but does nothing

Tags: c++, checkbox, boolean, imgui

I have a few Checkboxes assigned to variables. But when i click them nothing happens. It registers when they're clicked because it goes slightly bright but no tick appears. The bool that appears in the loop is static so that should not effect this.
Code

```
static bool aimColor = false;
ImGui::Checkbox(skCrypt("Show Aim Color Picker"), &aimColor);
```

The aimColor Bool does not change at all

Comment: That code runs correctly and changes the bool on dear imgui, v1.82 - can you post the full code?

Comment: Im not on my pc rn but that normally works but its not actually changing anything atm. Not to sure why